# Setting up ethernet connect between 2 Win7 system

Tags: windows-7, networking, ethernet, svn

I am trying to setup SVN server in a computer and access repository from the server from another computer. Server and client works fine when they reside in one computer, but problem starts when I try to connect 2 Computers with Win7 running in them, with ethernet cable (and a switch between). But seems like they are not communicating with each other and are not discoverable in the network.

What I have done so far:

1. Hardcored 2 different IP to the PC's: 192.168.1.20 / 192.168.1.21
2. Enabled Function Discovery Resource Publisher service on both computers.
3. Enabled SSDP Discovery.
4. Enabled UPnP Device host.
5. Made the 2 computers discoverable to one another.
6. Pinged between them -- but all timed outs are returned.

--
UPDATE:
I'm receiving the following error while pinging from 192.168.1.20:

```
Reply from 192.168.1.20: Destination host unreachable.
```

Can someone help me with setting up this?

I just have one constraint: None of the computers should connect to Internet. Its a closed setup.

Comment: Do you have firewalls turned on on each machine?  If it is an isolated network then you can safely turn them off to test.  Also compare `ifconfig` results on each machine to see if they are on the same subnet etc.

Comment: @PeterM Yes the firewall is turned on currently. it is here for security measures. Although I can try to test connect by turning them off, but in a long run firewall has to run.

Comment: Turning the firewalls off for testing is OK .. then if that is the problem you can create rules to let specific programs through.  Firewalls are always a pain for this sort of stuff.  But the W7 firewall is pretty easy to configure.

Comment: I have turned off the firewall but still it is not connecting. Is there any 3rd party tool that I can use.

Comment: Which firewall did you turn off?  The ping originator? The ping recipient? Both?

Comment: Both. But nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

In the default configuration, Windows 7 hosts do not reply to ping. Since this is a closed setup, you can safely enable ping following the advice at the
[Microsoft Community website](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/how-to-enable-ping-response-in-windows-7/5aff5f8d-f138-4c9a-8646-5b3a99f1cae6?auth=1).

As far as the other applications not connecting, suggest using Wireshark to make sure traffic is getting past Windows firewall.

Comment: Care to take the time to include all relevant information from the link you believe is relevant to this question?  Link-only answers are not that helpful to the community as a whole.

Comment: Wireshark is not showing anything on the other computer. So basically when I ping, i only receive `Destination host unreachable` error.

Comment: If you run Wireshark on 192.168.1.21, do you see the ARP frame from 192.168.1.20? Typically when you see "Destination host unreachable", it indicates that the host is not responding to ARP.

Comment: @ikis: Actually, may I suggest running Wireshark on both machines and attempting your ping from .20 to .21 again? If you do not see an ARP request on .20, the problem is likely the network configuration of .20...make sure the subnet mask is set to something like 255.255.255.0. If you see the ARP request on .20, but not on .21, then the problem is likely a broken cable, or the switchports you are using are in different VLANs.